# Force close when test my gps location getting and calculate total distance I travelled in android

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, locationlistener

Recently I am learning about using gps and marker to pinpoint my current location. And now I try to modify so that the code will be able to keep track my current location and calculate my total distance travelled when there is updated in my location. At the beginning, it works find. But after 2-3 minutes, my app start hang and prompt me force close as no response from my application.

Below is my code:

```
public class WhereAmINowActivity extends Activity {
//declaration of variables

public void getPrevActivityValue(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // get the value from prev activity
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.start_distance);
    getPrevActivityValue();
    btnStart = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
    btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    distance = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distance);

    locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, TWO_MIN, HUNDRED_METERS ,locationListener);

    addListenerOnBtnStart();
    addListenerOnBtnStop();
}

public void addListenerOnBtnStart(){
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView){
        if(!startPressed){
// Initialize the variables of current and old location coordinates

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            // Do nothing
        }
      }
    });
}

public void addListenerOnBtnStop(){
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View paramAnonymousView){
        try{

            if(connected to internet is true)

// Do something here

                }
                else{
// prompt message to notify user connectivity is not available
                }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
}


  private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          updateWithNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
          updateWithNewLocation(null);
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){ }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
                                    Bundle extras){ }
      };

      private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

// Update the current location, old coordinates and get the address 

        }


}
```

Some of the value is passed from previous activity by using getIntent().

can anyone help me figure out which part I done it wrongly?

Addition:
I removed the overlay and tested on merely the location listener.
I found that when it run about 2-3minutes, the interface of my app will not response on what I pressed (as I declare two button- start and stop). When I pressed the stop button, there is nothing happened, then a force close message is prompt to me. Is this the part I did wrong? How should I correct it so that it can work as like a normal distance calculation when I walk by using GPS?

Comment: As it stands, you may find your question may get closed for being too localised (i.e. it provides no help to anybody but yourself). You may want to look at trimming all the unnecessary code out and showing a smaller section of code that demonstrates the problem in a more general sense. After doing this, you may find you'll have found the problem! :)

Comment: Please post logcat output.

Comment: I had tested with just the location listener and my distance calculation part. This might be the part that cause the force close message prompt. But I had no idea how to correct it. Can you provide further advice. Thank you so much.

Comment: Shreya, I was tested on my real device, so I am not able to get any log for the error message.

Comment: I think I found out the root cause (correct me if I am wrong). The gps location getting is working fine. Only when the button pressed, which after 2-3 minutes the app running, it is not prompt the message.
So, I believed is the button code problem, where the condition checking is failed, which meant when the network connection is poor or not available and when the button is pressed, it caused the app hang and end up with force close event. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this exact problem in my open source Gps Tracker. The full working android project is here:

https://github.com/nickfox/GpsTracker/tree/master/phoneClients/android

and the class that does the tracking is below. You want to take a look at the variable called totalDistanceInMeters.

```
package com.websmithing.gpstracker;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class LocationService extends Service implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

    // use the websmithing defaultUploadWebsite for testing and then check your
    // location with your browser here: https://www.websmithing.com/gpstracker/displaymap.php
    private String defaultUploadWebsite;

    private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationClient locationClient;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        defaultUploadWebsite = getString(R.string.default_upload_website);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // if we are currently trying to get a location and the alarm manager has called this again,
        // no need to start processing a new location.
        if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
            currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
            startTracking();
        }

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startTracking() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startTracking");

        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            locationClient = new LocationClient(this,this,this);

            if (!locationClient.isConnected() || !locationClient.isConnecting()) {
                locationClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "unable to connect to google play services.");
        }
    }

    protected void sendLocationDataToWebsite(Location location) {
        // formatted for mysql datetime format
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date(location.getTime());

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("com.websmithing.gpstracker.prefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        float totalDistanceInMeters = sharedPreferences.getFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", 0f);

        boolean firstTimeGettingPosition = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", true);

        if (firstTimeGettingPosition) {
            editor.putBoolean("firstTimeGettingPosition", false);
        } else {
            Location previousLocation = new Location("");
            previousLocation.setLatitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLatitude", 0f));
            previousLocation.setLongitude(sharedPreferences.getFloat("previousLongitude", 0f));

            float distance = location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
            totalDistanceInMeters += distance;
            editor.putFloat("totalDistanceInMeters", totalDistanceInMeters);
        }

        editor.putFloat("previousLatitude", (float)location.getLatitude());
        editor.putFloat("previousLongitude", (float)location.getLongitude());
        editor.apply();

        final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();
        requestParams.put("latitude", Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
        requestParams.put("longitude", Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));

        Double speedInMilesPerHour = location.getSpeed()* 2.2369;
        requestParams.put("speed",  Integer.toString(speedInMilesPerHour.intValue()));

        try {
            requestParams.put("date", URLEncoder.encode(dateFormat.format(date), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}

        requestParams.put("locationmethod", location.getProvider());

        if (totalDistanceInMeters > 0) {
            requestParams.put("distance", String.format("%.1f", totalDistanceInMeters / 1609)); // in miles,
        } else {
            requestParams.put("distance", "0.0"); // in miles
        }

        requestParams.put("username", sharedPreferences.getString("userName", ""));
        requestParams.put("phonenumber", sharedPreferences.getString("appID", "")); // uuid
        requestParams.put("sessionid", sharedPreferences.getString("sessionID", "")); // uuid

        Double accuracyInFeet = location.getAccuracy()* 3.28;
        requestParams.put("accuracy",  Integer.toString(accuracyInFeet.intValue()));

        Double altitudeInFeet = location.getAltitude() * 3.28;
        requestParams.put("extrainfo",  Integer.toString(altitudeInFeet.intValue()));

        requestParams.put("eventtype", "android");

        Float direction = location.getBearing();
        requestParams.put("direction",  Integer.toString(direction.intValue()));

        final String uploadWebsite = sharedPreferences.getString("defaultUploadWebsite", defaultUploadWebsite);

        LoopjHttpClient.get(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - success", uploadWebsite, requestParams, responseBody, headers, statusCode, null);
                stopSelf();
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, org.apache.http.Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
                LoopjHttpClient.debugLoopJ(TAG, "sendLocationDataToWebsite - failure", uploadWebsite, requestParams, errorResponse, headers, statusCode, e);
                stopSelf();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "position: " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude() + " accuracy: " + location.getAccuracy());

            // we have our desired accuracy of 500 meters so lets quit this service,
            // onDestroy will be called and stop our location uodates
            if (location.getAccuracy() < 500.0f) {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                sendLocationDataToWebsite(location);
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        if (locationClient != null && locationClient.isConnected()) {
            locationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            locationClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the
     * client finishes successfully. At this point, you can
     * request the current location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");

        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setInterval(1000); // milliseconds
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000); // the fastest rate in milliseconds at which your app can handle location updates
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the
     * location client drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.e(TAG, "onDisconnected");

        stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");

        stopLocationUpdates();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```